# 14.04.01 upgrade and No Wi-Fi. BCM4312

Tags: wireless, 14.04

I have a Laptop Dell Mini 910 Inspirion Wireless card: Wireless 802.11g Mini Card 32-bit Itel Atom Processor, N270 512K cashe, 1.60GHZ, 533MHZ FSB

Did a 14.04.01 upgrade and do not have Wi-Fi.
Same thing happened on previous upgrade to 12.03.3 LTS. Solution was to get 2480236-Broadcom Firmware.tar.gz. I tried this and NOTHING.

Troubleshooting thus far:

Type of card: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] {rev 01}

I can see the empty (no signal) Wi-Fi ICON.

ran command:nm-tool

State: disconnected Device: eth0 Type:r8169 state: unavailable default: no HW Address: 00:21:70:D7:EB:cc Capabilities: Carrier detect: yes Wired Properties Carrier: off

ran command: iwconfig

lo no wireless extensions. eth0 no wireless extensions.

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this (matches drivers to 14e4):

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43

I've had problems with the broadcom wireless in my netbook and found that unfortunately the solution for one release does not necessarily work for the following one.